# can not query values from windows registry

Tags: c++, winapi

I writing program for the Windows registry and trying to query values from it, but even if I running my own program with the permissions of Administrator, I can not read all parameters and got error code 5 - Access Denied for some values. But at the same time standard regedit could show me that value. What did i doing wrong?

I have a class for the registry RegistryClass

RegistryClass.h:

```
class RegistryClass
{
    HKEY hKey;
    public:
        int GetCountOfKeys();
        bool OpenKey(HKEY key, std::string path);
        void EnumKeys(char ** result, int * count);
        ...
}
```

RegistryClass.cpp

```
#include "RegistryClass.h"
...
bool RegistryClass::OpenKey(HKEY key, std::string path)
{
    if(RegOpenKeyExA(key,path.c_str(),NULL,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return true;
    }
    hKey = NULL;
    return false;
}

int RegistryClass::GetCountOfKeys()
{
    DWORD count  = 0;
    char keyName [256];
    DWORD len = 255;
    while(1)
    {
        if(RegEnumKeyExA(hKey,count,keyName,&len,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            break;

        count++;
        len = 255;
    }
    return count;
}

void RegistryClass::EnumKeys(char ** result, int * count)
{
    if(hKey == NULL)
        return;
    *count = 0;
    DWORD dwIndex = 0;          // current key
    char keyName [255];         // current key name
    DWORD lpcchName = 255;      // name length
    int error;
    do
    {
        error = RegEnumKeyExA(hKey,dwIndex,keyName,&lpcchName,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        if(error == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            memcpy(result[(*count)],keyName,lpcchName);
            (*count)++;
        }
        dwIndex++;
        lpcchName = 255;
    }while(error == ERROR_SUCCESS);
}
```

in main program i trying to retrive keys

```
void MainWindow::InitializeFirstState()
{
    item_HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    item_HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT->setText(0,"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT");
    // and other keys
    ...
    tree->addTopLevelItem(item_HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT);
    ...
    AddInternalKeys(item_HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,true);
    ...
}

...

void AddInternalKeys(QTreeWidgetItem * item, bool rec)
{
    std::string currentPath = GetFullPathKey(item);
    // first key name
    std::string keyName = GetParentKeyName(item);

    RegistryClass * regC = new RegistryClass();
    HKEY key;

    if(strcmp(keyName.c_str(),"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT") == 0)
    {
        key = HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
    }
    else if(strcmp(keyName.c_str(),"HKEY_CURRENT_USER") == 0)
    {
        key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    }
    else if(strcmp(keyName.c_str(),"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE") == 0)
    {
        key = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    }
    else if(strcmp(keyName.c_str(),"HKEY_USERS") == 0)
    {
        key = HKEY_USERS;
    }
    else // HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG
    {
        key = HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG;
    }

    if(regC->OpenKey(key,currentPath) == true)
    {
         internalLog->print("key opened succesfully\n");
    }
    else internalLog->print("key was not opened\n");

    int count = regC->GetCountOfKeys();

    char ** keys = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * count);
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        keys[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
        memset(keys[i],0,sizeof(char) * 256);
    }
    regC->EnumKeys(keys,&count);

    regC->CloseKey();
    delete regC;
    QTreeWidgetItem * newItem;
    count--;
    while(count >= 0)
    {
        newItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        newItem->setText(0,keys[count]);
        item->addChild(newItem);
        std::string str = keys[count];
        AddKeyNames(newItem,str);
        free(keys[count]);
        if(rec == true)
            AddInternalKeys(newItem,false);
        count--;
    }
    free(keys);
}
```

Comment: You can post your code you did so far :-)

Comment: It would also help to know which keys you are having difficulty reading.

Comment: LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE subkeys in USERS CURRENT_CONFIG\SYSTEM and some other

Comment: You can't read those keys, only the System account can.  They contain sensitive security and hardware configuration related settings.  The simple rule is that if you can't see them in Regedit.exe then your program can't see them either.

Comment: I can see some keys in regedit but not in my program.

Comment: Please provide complete code. We do not know what your `hKey` is and how you retrieved that. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for too much access. You are asking for `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` when all you actually need is `KEY_READ`. You do not have all-access permission, but you do have read permission.