# RegOpenKeyEx() fails with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHIENE when trying to get the "Path" variable

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, registry

I am trying to get the "Path" variable in my MFC application.
Please find the code.

```
HKEY hKey;
char data[256] = "";
unsigned long length = 255;
LPCTSTR keyPath = TEXT("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment");
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyPath, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    length = 255;
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "Path", 0, NULL, (unsigned char *)data, &length);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

But the `RegOpenKeyEx` function fails. Thanks in advance.

Comment: GetLastError() won't set in this case. RegOpenKeyEx() returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (Error code 5).

Comment: you need `KEY_READ` instead `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` if you want only read

Comment: @RbMm That is worked. thanks. :) Simple fix. :(

Comment: @Prasanth - never use fixed size buffers here. and use W instead A api

Comment: @RbMm I will take care that too. Thanks

Comment: @RbMm How can I use a dynamic buffer instead of 'data'. Do I need to use std::Vector? Here I am limiting the length as 256. I am new to MFC.

Comment: @RbMm I have to append a string to "Path". Then need to reset the value. I am getting the same ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED while using the RegSetValueEx() function. Am I lacking an admin privilege?

Comment: @Prasanth you cannot write to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry hive from a non elevated process. Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/uxguide/winenv-uac

Comment: @RbMm I just found it after a research. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @Prasanth you can answer your own question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can not query values from windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175746/can-not-query-values-from-windows-registry)